# Not able to read data from the file in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am a beginner c++ programmer and I was accustomed to using Visual Studio before, but i am now using mac and i use xcode now. In xcode, i am not able to read data from the file (so i am also not able to get the output.) Which setting should i change in xcode to read data from the file(the file is in the same folder as the project) properly ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//in thefile.txt i only have a string "hello"
int main() {
    string text; //since i only have a string in the file. So this is a variable representation for it
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("thefile.txt");
    myfile >> text; //extract the word from the file
    cout << "The following is the data in the file: " << text <<endl; //trying to print The following is the data in the file: hello
    return 0;
}
 //Output is "The following is the data in the file: "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way is to use a fully qualified file name to take the guesswork out of it. If you're not sure of the full name, you can open up a window in the OS X **Terminal** program, type "file ", and then drag your file from a Finder window onto that command line. Terminal will fill in the full path. "file" is an innocuous command that will tell you information about your file type. But the important thing is, you will have a full path that you can then copy from Terminal and paste into your code.

If your file path has blanks in it, you may have to manually remove the backslash characters that will appear.

Xcode doesn't have a setting per se (that I know of) to determine what directory is active when you launch your program. But a full path takes the guesswork out of it.

Comment: Thank you. It helped. I also found a way to do this through xcode (product > scheme > edit scheme > options (inside run) and then changing directory to the directory where your code is.